# Creating a 'Save As' button for a file generated on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

On our UI, we allow a user to complete some details, and then we need them to generate a PDF file based on the details entered. So, I make a WebAPI call to the server, posting some details, which in turn generates the binary file.

We would prefer not to save the binary file, but instead, produce a 'Download Now' button, which downloads the PDF when it's ready.

I was hoping to generate the file, and return the result to a state variable.

```
this.setState({ myFile: result });
```

Where result is what I get back from the API.

And then when '`result != null'`, enable a Download button. When the user clicks that button, the `this.state.myFile` will download ... with a name that I provide (via code).

I'm not sure if saving binary data in state is even possible.

Is there a way to have a button that triggers a download from a state variable? Last resort would be to generate and store the file on the server, and then provide a link - but if we can store it in state and allow the user to click a 'Download' button once the file is in state (They're small - approx between 100k and 300k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like below

```
var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(result);
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = file;
a.download = "Name of PDF";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: Indirectly it will create an object into DOMString and later user will hit URL and download object. I'm right?

Comment: Not later, it will download directly.. If you want to download it later on clicking some button, instead of creating new element you can use existing element itself..